# Automated test for Windev

Tags: automated-tests, qtp, windev

I'm trying to automate some manual test on a Windev windows application. I have tried with QTP 11, QTP can recognize the objects but for some of them like Combobox, Winlist, QTP cannot do any actions. So I would like to know if there is other tools could do the automated test.

Thanks a lot in advance

Allen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use Coded UI Test Recorder, which is a built-in feature of Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition.

BTW, You should try to use Microsoft Spy++ to Inspect the elements of the win form. If the elements could be recognized and inspected by Microsoft Spy++, you could use White or some other automated testing framework to handle them directly...

Answer (score 1):

WINDEV has an automated testing function built into the softare. It can be a record and playback or coded for testing your application. Parameter driven testing also is available. I've used it with my WINDEV applications. A good feature is if you port the applicatin to WEBDEV (web site use) the testing can be reused. OR have you tried TESTCOMPLETE? Interesting product for automated testing.